# Java Keytool asking for key store password after typing the comand?1?

Tags: android, keystore

I am from brazil and im trying to generate a keystore and after going to the bin of my jre7/bin in here its "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin" i try to run this code:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

But it is asking me for a password after that and i cant type anything like, i pressed all the keyboard keys and nothing was writen all i can do is press enter and the key is not generated... Has anyone ever went through this? In portuguese he asks me for: "Informe a senha da área de armazenamento de chaves:"

Answer (score 2):

You have to type password, which will be used to encrypt the key store and then confirm it. 
Passwords are not shadowed to the console, so it looks empty for you.

You may specify password in the command line itself with `storepass` and `keypass` parametrs

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore \
-storepass mypassword123 -keypass mypassword123 \
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

`storepass` is the password to encrypt the whole key store, and `keypass` is used to encrypt the key entry. Their values do not have to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

if in debug mode use **android**

I hope it helped you